# OOP Quicksort in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, quicksort

I need help with a Python homework, I need to write a quick sort code in OOP, what am I doing wrong, that it does not work?

```
class sort:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array
        array = [4,3,1,3,5,6,4,67,7,5]
    def quick_sort(array):
        if len(array) <= 1:
            return(array)
        else:
            smaller = []
            bigger = []
            pivot = array[0]
            for number in array[1:]:
                if number < pivot:
                    smaller.append(number)
                else:
                    bigger.append(number)
            return quick_sort(smaller) + [pivot] + quicksort(bigger)
        return array
```

Comment: You may want to add a bit more details to your question. What exactly "does not work"? What does you code do, and what you expect it to do instead?

Comment: After calling this code, it does not receive any response in the terminal, instead it should give me a sorted list

Comment: @Piotrek Please [edit] to turn this into a [mcve], or at least add how you're calling the code, what the expected behaviour is, and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues I can see:

- Your `quick_sort` function starts from your class `sort`, so it must take as arguments `(self, array)`.
- Your `liczba` variable is not declared.
- When returning your function, you should not call it again (Notion of recursion)

Answer (score 0):

```
#%% Quik sort oop
class QuickSort:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def qsort(self):
        if len(self.lst) < 2:
            return self.lst

        pivot = self.lst[0]
        less_than_pivot = [i for i in self.lst[1:] if i <= pivot]
        more_than_pivot = [i for i in self.lst[1:] if i > pivot]

        less = QuickSort(less_than_pivot)
        more = QuickSort(more_than_pivot)
        return less.qsort() + [pivot] + more.qsort()

### Driver Code ###
arr = QuickSort([2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 0, -2, 4])
arr.qsort()
```